# Changing colour of listboxitems which is binded with a database source?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have a Listbox which is binded to an sql database. What I'm trying to do is compare the item ID of each item in the list box to a set of ID's in isolated storage and change the colour of the listbox item if they match.

```
void svc_ViewLecturesPollQuestionsCompleted(object sender, ViewLecturesPollQuestionsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // bind profiles to listbox
            PollQuestionsList.ItemsSource = e.Result;              

            for(int i = 0; i < PollQuestionsList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = PollQuestionsList.Items[i] as PollQuestion;
                ListBoxItem listBoxItem = PollQuestionsList.Items[i] as ListBoxItem;
                foreach (var Key in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Keys)
                {
                    if (Key.ToString() == item.ID.ToString())
                    {
                        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));    
                        listBoxItem.Background = brush;                            
                    }
                }            
            }
        }
   }
```

Here is the method in which I'm trying to do it but where I instantiate the listboxitem 'listBoxItem' its saying its null. So I get the object reference is not set to an instance of an object error. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `ItemsSource` of a ListBox simply means *"When this ListBox loads, loop through these items, and for each one add a `<ListBoxItem>` to the ListBox, and set the `ListBoxItem.DataContext` equal to the item."*. There is no way to access these `ListBoxItems` until they get generated.

The `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ListBox` can be used to change any properties of  the `ListBoxItem` that's generated. For example, you could use it to set the `ListBoxItem.Background` property based on some value in your data item.

In your case, I would add a boolean property to the `PollQuestion` item such as `IsInIsolatedStorage`, and bind the `ListBoxItem.Background` property to that boolean value using a Converter or a DataTrigger.

If you were to use a `DataTrigger`, your code would look something like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsInIsolatedStorage}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Yellow" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Or if you used a converter to convert the `bool` value to a `Brush` value, it would look something like this :

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding IsInIsolatedStorage, Converter={StaticResource MyCustomConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Converters are very simple to create, and are used to convert an item of one datatype to another for binding purposes. You can google for plenty of examples, but it would look something like this :

```
public class MyCustomConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ListBoxItem listBoxItem = PollQuestionsList.Items[i] as ListBoxItem;
is null because it's invalid cast. 
Check on Debug the real type of the element and cast it poperly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The real type of what element? It is a list of PollQuestions but I'm wanting to select a ListBoxItem so I can change it's background colour.